# Common Image format for all android camera Phones

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using a customized Camera in my applications. I am trying to set my camera parameter as

```
params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
params.setJpegQuality(1);
```

With the above code, it works fine in most of my android device (Samsung Galaxy , Ace , S2 with Android version 4.0 - 4.1), but when I run the application on Nexus4 Or HTC with `Android version 4.1 Or 4.2` , the image quality is completely crumpled.

If I remove '`params.setJpegQuality(1);'` from the code, then  it works fine on Nexus4 Or HTC , but lot of whiteScreen issues on other android devices mentioned above.

Please help to resolve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params.setJpegQuality(1);`// this is very low quality

```
public void setJpegQuality (int quality)
```

Sets Jpeg quality of captured picture.

Parameters

```
 quality    the JPEG quality of captured picture. The range is 1 to 100, with 100 being the best. [link here][1]
```

//for better quality give `params.setJpegQuality(80);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I set params.setJpegQuality(80), I get white screen issues when setting the image to an html page. do you have any suggestion on that?